# Putting an IF statement inside a foreach and missing out entry

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach

I have an IF statement inside a foreach loop getting data from an XML file. I then want to run through each entry in the XML file and skip putting this into a table if it doesn't meet a certain criteria. The code below is just skipping every entry and it's returning blank with nothing being put in a table.

PHP CODE :

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("movie.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->children() as $movie) :

 if($xml->sad<=$_GET['happiness']
 && $xml->agitated<=$_GET['calmness']
 && $xml->tired<=$_GET['tired']
 && $xml->scared<=$_GET['scared'] )
 {?>
   <td align="center" valign="center">
   <img src="<?php echo $movie->path?>" width="150px" alt="<?php echo $movie->descrip?>"/>
   <br />
   <?php echo $movie->name ?>
   </td>
<?php } endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

XML CODE:

```
<movie>
        <name>Harry Potter</name>
        <path>images/harry.jpg</path>
        <sad>50</sad>
        <agitated>25</agitated>
        <tired>50</tired>
        <scared>75</scared>
</movie>
```

Comment: Possibly your GET variable and/or the XML node are being treated as strings, not integers, so the <= comparison is failing?

Comment: Another suggestion: Should e.g. `$xml->sad<=$_GET['happiness']` be `$movie->sad<=$_GET['happiness']`?

Comment: I've tried converting them but still to no avail ! I'm completely stumped

Comment: renaming it to the correct $movie variable has gone somewhere but not fixed it completely, it's now gone from displaying blank to just displaying my error message in the else{ statement after!

Comment: I've managed to get it working with just one of the IF statements, but when i try to add other statements within it it just errors

Comment: Ok, is your XML supposed to contain one movie, as it does currently, or multiple movies? With the XML file you provided I think your foreach is looping over each node (tired, scared, etc.) when I suspect it is supposed to be iterating entire movies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that your XML file contains one movie, so instead of looping over multiple movies your `foreach` is looping over the child nodes of a *single* movie.

Here is a version that I think should do what you want:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file(dirname("movie.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->children() as $movie) :  
 if($movie->sad<=$_GET['happiness']
   && $movie->agitated<=$_GET['calmness']
   && $movie->tired<=$_GET['tired']
   && $movie->scared<=$_GET['scared'] )
   {?>
     <td align="center" valign="center">
     <img src="<?php echo $movie->path?>" width="150px" alt="<?php echo $movie->descrip?>"/>
     <br />
     <?php echo $movie->name ?>
     </td>
  <?php } endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

XML:

```
<movies>
    <movie>
            <name>Harry Potter</name>
            <path>images/harry.jpg</path>
            <sad>50</sad>
            <agitated>25</agitated>
            <tired>50</tired>
            <scared>75</scared>
    </movie>
    <movie>
            <name>Harry Potter</name>
            <path>images/harry.jpg</path>
            <sad>50</sad>
            <agitated>25</agitated>
            <tired>50</tired>
            <scared>75</scared>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Note how the xml file now contains multiple `<movie>` nodes, each inside the `<movies>` node and how `$xml->sad` becomes `$movie->sad` etc.